# Unable to locate executable file: 'bash' error for a simple script on Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I get the following error if I run my azure devops pipeline:

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the 
file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file 
mode to verify the file is executable.
```

I tried it with my self hosted agent and with microsoft hosted agent, both of them have the same error.

Here is my pipeline:

```
trigger:
 - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
 - script: 
    echo Starting the build
    ./gradlew build
   displayName: 'Build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the workingDirectory for the script like documnted here: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml&viewFallbackFrom=vsts)

```yaml
- script: # script path or inline
  workingDirectory: #
  displayName: #
```

For example if you have a repository with a structure like this:

```
RepoName
 - Folder1
   - scriptToRun
 - Folder2
```

The value for workingDirectory would be:

```yaml
- script: ./scriptToRun
  workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Folder1'
  displayName: 'Build'
```

Or you can probably skip the workingDirectory and give a full path to the script.
Note also tht this example is for a single repository checkout. If you checkout multiple repos the path would be different.

Comment: I am facing the same error for Inline Script. How can I resolve it?

Comment: The error is saying it can't find bash. It's not saying that it can't find the script.

Comment: Which does not make sense, because Bash is preinstalled on Microsoft Agents. You just execute the task based on the documentation:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash?view=azure-devops and it should work. And i assume he got the "echo Starting the build" in the console logs but failed on "./gradlew build" which means, there is indeed bash on the machine. I actually had the same issue and the same error message and it was a path issue.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue and after renaming a variable that it was named `path`, it worked.

Comment: Just had the same issue, fixed by removing the variable. looking back it makes sense you dont want te be setting "path".

Comment: Probably the most helpful answer ever. And the most weired behavior I ever experienced in Azure DevOps.

Comment: What variable do you mean?

Comment: @Enrico, a variable named `path`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, initially I had given my self-hosted agent, a PAT with access to the *Agent Pools Read/Manage permission*, as this is what it states in the docs, and then I started getting this error, even though bash was clearly in my PATH environment variable.

I then removed the agent, added it back, and this time gave it a PAT with *Full Access*.

I no longer receive the bash error.