# Azure DevOps YAML pipeline matrix strategy - [error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline where I want to build and push several docker images to ECR. Everything works fine if I use a task for each service without using a matrix, but I want to reduce the build time by parallel creating the tasks using a matrix with the variables each service needs:

```
name: Build Docker images and push to Registry

trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
- group: AWS
- name: DOCKER_REPOSITORY_URL
  value: $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID).dkr.ecr.$(AWS_REGION).amazonaws.com
strategy:
  maxParallel: 8
  matrix:
    a-server:
      service: a-server
      path: somepath
    b-server:
      service: b-server
      path: somepath
    c-server:
      service: c-server
      path: somepath
    d-server:
      service: d-server
      path: somepath
    e-server:
      service: e-server
      path: somepath
    f-server:
      service: f-server
      path: somepath
    g-server:
      service: g-server
      path: somepath
    h-server:
      service: h-server
      path: somepath

steps:

- script: |
    aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
  env:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID)
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: $(AWS_ACCOUNT_ID)
    AWS_REGION: $(AWS_REGION)
  displayName: 'Login to AWS'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set last tag to variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $VERSION_TAG = git describe --tags (git rev-list --tags --max-count=1)
      Write-Host("##vso[task.setvariable variable=VERSION_TAG]$VERSION_TAG")
      Write-Host("##vso[build.addbuildtag]$VERSION_TAG")
      Write-Host($VERSION_TAG)

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    Dockerfile: $(path)/Dockerfile
    buildContext: $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)
    repository: $(DOCKER_REPOSITORY_URL)/organization/$(service)
    tags: |
      $(VERSION_TAG)
```

Error:

```
Generating script.
Script contents:
aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID.dkr.ecr.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'bash'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
```

I already went through several other posts with similar issues, but solutions, unfortunately, did not help and were not matrix-related.

**Note**: This error is not isolated to `aws` command, during my debug I also tried others, even sourcing the profile, but it fails with the same.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480005/unable-to-locate-executable-file-bash-error-for-a-simple-script-on-azure-devo

Comment: Hi, @VincentBitter thanks for your response. Yeah, I went to that one and others with similar errors, but the solution did not solve mine. This works perfectly, builds and pushes images to ECR if I create a task for each Dockerfile, it only starts to fail when using a matrix. I thought I could be missing something from the matrix functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You issue here comes from `path` phrase which you use in matrix configuration. If you change it to `imagePath` for instance all should work

```yaml
strategy:
  maxParallel: 8
  matrix:
    a_server:
      service: a-server
      imagePath: somepath
    b_server:
      service: b-server
      imagePath: somepath
    c_server:
      service: c-server
      imagePath: somepath
    d_server:
      service: d-server
      imagePath: somepath
    e_server:
      service: e-server
      imagePath: somepath
    f_server:
      service: f-server
      imagePath: somepath
    g_server:
      service: g-server
      imagePath: somepath
    h_server:
      service: h-server
      imagePath: somepath
```

Comment: Changing 'path' to 'somePath' helped me in solving the following error:

##[error]The term 'pwsh.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

The agent was not able to resolve the path of the powershell executable due the use of path in the matrix.